# A bound of the $L^p$ norm uning the weak Lebesgue norms.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The question is about the following proof.
[image]

I understand why we say $$d_f(\alpha)\leq \min\left(\frac{\|f\|_{p,\infty}^{p}}{\alpha^p},\frac{\|f\|_{q,\infty}^{q}}{\alpha^q}\right).$$

It is the consequence of the definition of the weak Lebesgue norm $$\|f\|_{p,\infty}=\sup { \lambda (D_f(\lambda))^{1/p}}$$ where $D_f$ is the distribution function.

**QUESTION 1:** Am I correct at this stage?

I understand how we get first equality. But I dont understand how we get the second equality
[image]

Also I dont understand how we get third and fourth equalities.

**QUESTION 2:** Can you give me some hints to handle this proof? I reread previous material in this book several times and did not find any hint.

Maybe it depends on the constant $B$ which we introduced. I dont know the intuition behind this constant also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Q1**, as you pointed out, since $f$ belongs to $L^{p, \infty}$ as well as to $L^{q, \infty}$, the following two inequalities hold simultaneously
\begin{align*}
    d_f(\alpha)\leq \frac{\|f\|_{p, \infty}^p}{\alpha^p},\\
    d_f(\alpha)\leq \frac{\|f\|_{q, \infty}^q}{\alpha^q},
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{align*}
    d_f(\alpha)\leq \min\left(\frac{\|f\|_{p, \infty}^p}{\alpha^p}, \frac{\|f\|_{q, \infty}^q}{\alpha^q}\right).
\end{align*}

Now **Q2**. The constant $B$ is chosen to split up the integral in a convenient way, with the aim to handle the $\min$ function appearing from the above inequality. You first use the layer-cake representation formula and then the inequality of the first step. Observe that when $0\leq \alpha\leq B$ a little bit of algebraic manipulation leads us to
\begin{align*}
    \alpha^{q-p}\leq \frac{\|f\|_{q, \infty}^q}{\|f\|_{p, \infty}^p} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\|f\|_{p, \infty}^p}{\alpha^p}\leq \frac{\|f\|_{q, \infty}^q}{\alpha^q}
\end{align*}
hence in such interval
\begin{align*}
    \min\left(\frac{\|f\|_{p, \infty}^p}{\alpha^p}, \frac{\|f\|_{q, \infty}^q}{\alpha^q}\right)=\frac{\|f\|_{p, \infty}^p}{\alpha^p}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, when $B\leq \alpha$ it holds
\begin{align*}
    \min\left(\frac{\|f\|_{p, \infty}^p}{\alpha^p}, \frac{\|f\|_{q, \infty}^q}{\alpha^q}\right)=\frac{\|f\|_{q, \infty}^q}{\alpha^q}.
\end{align*}
By spliting up the integral in these two intervals and using the above reasoning you get the equality $(5.15)/(1.1.25)$.